# How to send all .cs files to output directory after every build in Visual Studio 2012.

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, post-build-event, pre-build-event

I have some project what contains 3 dll libraries (one of them has 2 dependencies)

[image: Sturcture of project]

At the output folder of 'DLL parent' I need to have all source files of this 2 children. Moveover I want to save structure of this cs files by making 'cs' folder at output folder of DLL-parent, create subfolder with DLL-Child name there and copy all cs files of it to this folder.

For doing this I use post build events for DLL-Child. 
[image]

And at bottom level when I build just this dll it works perfect.

After I set this command line at DLL-Child post build event it's output is created with folder with source files inside.

But when I build whole solution problem that this folder is not copied from output of DLL-Child to output of DLL-Parent.
Why ? At references section of DLL-Parent I set 'Copy local' to true for dependencies but it copies nothing.

Comment: can i ask what possible reason you have to why you would need to copy the cs files at all?

Comment: But why do you want to do this?

Comment: We have a lot of different files with selenium tests of our web site. And those dlls are selenium tests. 
Our problem that when test fails we need to know that this issue is the same/ not the same as one or several days before. Shortly - somebody worked with this issue or not
Before we try to identify issue by code line but  tests are changing and code line changes too. So the idea is to save exact line of code  (taken from stacktrace and get from cs file) and check was test failed at this line or not with the same error message

Comment: That doesn't work because the CS files are not part of the reference. Can't you set the "Copy to output" property for the files to "Always"? (I'm not sure whether the property has that name, as I'm using a German VS)

Comment: I have alrady tried to set 'copy always' and it work till I have the same file names at different dlls. In my case I have a lot of files and names are sometimes the same. Problem is that that dll what is bult next overrides files of previous one

Answer (score 0):

Have your files be exported in separate folders per project. With this simple post build script (it's better to set it as post build event and select `on successful build` so as to not copy it each time but only when a build has been done properly)

```
copy "$(ProjectDir)FolderName\*" "PathYouWantYourFilesCopiedTo"
```

You can output all files from specific folder in your project.
You do not need checks for folders existing, VS does it on it's own. Create one build event for each folder of your files. If you have them in separate folders, nothing will overwrite nothing (as long as you maintain the folder structure in the output). And copy a whole folder is easier than copying file by file. 
Basically what you need to do is to specify explicitly folder names for the output location. That will stop overwriting of files.